# How can insert some text in HTML without clear the page?

Tags: javascript

I want to create some textfield by script,but how can I add some text between the textfield? 
I try to use "document.write" but it clear the page.

```
inform = document.getElementById('addinput');

  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "text";
  newinput.name = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.id = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.value = a;
  inform.appendChild(newinput);


  add = document.write('+');


  inform.appendChild(add);      
  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "text";
  newinput.name = "NumB" + i;
  newinput.id = "NumB" + i;
  newinput.value = b;
  inform.appendChild(newinput);
```

Comment: You're already adding text nodes with the rest of the code. Just do more of that.

Comment: Easy, don't use document.write

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you can create a span or paragraph element and use that to hold your text inbetween the two text boxes:

```
  inform = document.getElementById('addinput');

  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "text";
  newinput.name = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.id = "NumA" + i;
  newinput.value = a;
  inform.appendChild(newinput);


  add = document.createElement('span');
  add.innerHTML = "+";
  inform.appendChild(add);


  inform.appendChild(add);      
  newinput = document.createElement('input');
  newinput.type = "text";
  newinput.name = "NumB" + i;
  newinput.id = "NumB" + i;
  newinput.value = b;
  inform.appendChild(newinput);
```

Comment: By the way, I add a button in this script. Can I use the button to call other function. like this: newinput.onclick = "check();"; I try it but no response.